# Loop unrolling, Memory Access, and Recursive Throughput

Tags: c++, clang, x86-64, simd, loop-unrolling

Why does the compiler think it's profitable to load eight elements from one buffer, load 32 elements from the other buffer, do some calculations on eight elements of each buffer, and then load eight elements from the first buffer again instead of loading 32 elements from both buffers upfront?

Consider the following code snippet, which uses a SIMD library ([Google Highway](https://github.com/google/highway)):

```cpp
#include <hwy/highway.h>
namespace hn = hwy::HWY_NAMESPACE;

using T = float;

void MulAddLoop(const T* HWY_RESTRICT mul_array,
                const T* HWY_RESTRICT add_array,
                const size_t size, T* HWY_RESTRICT x_array) {
  const hn::ScalableTag<T> d;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += hn::Lanes(d)) {
    const auto mul = hn::Load(d, mul_array + i);
    const auto add = hn::Load(d, add_array + i);
    auto x = hn::Load(d, x_array + i);
    x = hn::MulAdd(mul, x, add);
    hn::Store(x, d, x_array + i);
  }
}
```

The assembly code associated with the main loop is:

```
        vmovaps ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + 4*rdx]
        vmovaps ymm1, ymmword ptr [rcx + 4*rdx]
        vmovaps ymm2, ymmword ptr [rcx + 4*rdx + 32]
        vmovaps ymm3, ymmword ptr [rcx + 4*rdx + 64]
        vmovaps ymm4, ymmword ptr [rcx + 4*rdx + 96]
        vfmadd213ps     ymm1, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsi + 4*rdx] # ymm1 = (ymm0 * ymm1) + mem
        vmovaps ymmword ptr [rcx + 4*rdx], ymm1
        vmovaps ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + 4*rdx + 32]
        vfmadd213ps     ymm0, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rsi + 4*rdx + 32] # ymm0 = (ymm2 * ymm0) + mem
        vmovaps ymmword ptr [rcx + 4*rdx + 32], ymm0
        vmovaps ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + 4*rdx + 64]
        vfmadd213ps     ymm0, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rsi + 4*rdx + 64] # ymm0 = (ymm3 * ymm0) + mem
        vmovaps ymmword ptr [rcx + 4*rdx + 64], ymm0
        vmovaps ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + 4*rdx + 96]
        vfmadd213ps     ymm0, ymm4, ymmword ptr [rsi + 4*rdx + 96] # ymm0 = (ymm4 * ymm0) + mem
        vmovaps ymmword ptr [rcx + 4*rdx + 96], ymm0
        add     rdx, 32
        add     r8, -4
        jne     .LBB0_8
```

See the entire example on [Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8b5KKo5zv) (taken from the highway project).

It seems to be me that the compiler decides to unroll four iterations of the loop and do the following:

- Load eight elements from the mul_array buffer
- Load 32 elements in four steps from the add_array buffer
- Do an FMA on eight elements and store the results in x_array
- Load 8 elements from the mul_array buffer
- ...

If I had done loop unrolling, I would have loaded 32 elements from each mul_array and add_array. Why did the compiler come to the conclusion that its decision was optimal? Are there too few registers for that? I find this particularly intriguing, as the [Intel Intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=vmovaps&ig_expand=4016) states an RT of 0.5 or 1/3 for the memory load, so I would have tried to load two or three elements from one buffer.

Comment: There are 16 ymm registers so that would have been plenty, although some of them are callee-save so using them would have make the prologue and epilogue bigger. In terms of execution speed of the main loop I don't think any of this matters

Comment: @harold: The OP's godbolt link is compiling for x86-64 System V where all vector registers are call-clobbered.  Unlike Windows x64 where only 5 can be used without saving/restoring (having a couple call-preserved XMM makes sense, but not that many.)

Comment: *Recursive Throughput* (in the title) - Did you mean *reciprocal* throughput, like how load throughput is 0.5c or 0.33c on recent Intel?  Given out-of-order exec, grouping loads together is not critical.  If any of the pointers are misaligned, grouping their loads mean that only every other load can be a cache-line split; with limited numbers of split buffers available in loads ports, alternating might have a small advantage over potentially 3 splits in a row.  But they'd probably schedule to different ports.

Comment: Semi-related: [AVX512 auto-vectorized C++ matrix-vector functions are much slower when source = destination, in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/137265808) - software-pipelining to hide some load-use latency can make a difference when there are moderate-length dep chains and cache-miss latency adding up.  Here you only have very short chains of FMA -> store so probably nothing to be gained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like reasonable instruction-scheduling to me.  At least one load from the two read-only arrays as early as possible gets started resolving cache and TLB misses on them.

Scheduling the first FMA (and load from `x`) before doing *all* the loads means there's some work to do if the ROB (reorder buffer) and/or scheduler (for un-executed uops) is nearly full with stalled work independent from this loop.

Intel P-cores use a mostly-unified scheduler, but E-cores, and AMD, use separate scheduling queues for each execution port.  This is probably not significant since even putting all the pure-loads from one iteration first, before all the FMAs+loads and then all the stores, would still only be a small fraction of the sizes of the scheduling and non-scheduling queues in the CPUs `-mtune=generic` is tuning for.  And this is `-march=haswell` code-gen anyway, where the scheduler was fully unified; any kind of uop can go in any entry.

The memory source operands for the FMAs are also the first access to the `add_array`.  IDK if clang is intentionally delaying that until after some of the loads from other arrays (perhaps to reduce cache conflict misses?), or to be just before the stores back to `x`, or just that's how it worked out.

But there's a few cycles of load latency from dispatching a load uop to an execution unit before the result is ready for use, so mostly scheduling the loads several instructions ahead of the instruction consuming their result is good to make out-of-order exec not have to work as hard.  (Or to have more capability to spare to hide actual cache misses, and overlap this work with surrounding code.)  With 3 loads + 1 store per FMA, that's going to be the bottleneck even in ideal conditions, even moreso than a dot product (2 loads per FMA, with dependency chains for FMAs.)

As @harold points out, clang is only using YMM0..5 here.  It's compiling for x86-64 System V, not Windows x64.  It might just be a coincidence that XMM6-15 are call-preserved in Windows x64, where the low 16 bytes of any of them would have to get saved/restored on the stack if used.  Or its heuristics might favour economizing on number of registers because that can be useful if you need others for constants, or if you *are* compiling for Windows.

---

So yeah, **if writing by hand,** I'd probably be inclined to start with a pure load from each of the three arrays (since FMA can use the memory source as a multiplicand or the addend, that's what the 132 vs. 213 vs. 231 stuff is about).  Then four memory-source FMAs, then four stores.

Doing loads before stores means memory-disambiguation doesn't have to work as hard, trying to predict whether a load is reloading a recent store or not.  (There is dynamic prediction for this; misprediction leads to a `machine_clears.memory_ordering` event.)

Also, I'd have avoided an indexed addressing mode for the FMA memory source and the store; that stops Intel P-cores from micro-fusing the load+FMA into a single uop for the front-end (*[Micro fusion and addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes)*), and it stops Skylake and earlier from using the port-7 store AGU, limiting them to 2 load + store-address uops executed per clock.  (https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/)

Clang and GCC seem to be totally unaware of un-lamination (indexed addressing modes not staying micro-fused after issue/rename), doing big unrolls while still spending 2 uops per instruction instead of using it to amortize the cost of an extra pointer increment.

MSVC knows the trick of subtracting pointers so one can be non-indexed, but doesn't know how to take advantage: it often uses the non-indexed addressing mode for a pure load, which is always a single uop.  The trick is  `sub rsi, rcx` / `sub rdi, rcx`, and pointer-increment `rcx` in the loop with `add rcx, 128` (or `sub rcx, -128` to allow an imm8).  So `x` elements can be referenced as `[rcx]` or `[rcx + 32]` or whatever, and `mul_array` or `add_array` elements are `[rsi + rcx]` or `[rdi + rcx]`.

This allows the stores and FMA source operands to be one-register addressing modes, saving code-size for both of them, and more importantly saving front-end uops on Intel and allowing use of the port-7 AGU on Haswell through Skylake.  (Ice Lake and later have two full-featured store AGU ports, and store-address uops never run on load ports, but un-lamination is still a thing.  https://uica.uops.info/ correctly models it.)

So yes there's a significant missed-optimization bug here, but not in the instruction scheduling (ordering).

Comment: Thanks for the illustrative answer - I could learn a lot from it.